# Procedural modeling of complex shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers

What is the best/easiest way to model something this:

Preferably procedural.

Also I need it to be rectangular in the finished result.

(I know it could be done afterwards with a boolean modifier but let's say I don't want to have to use this as a last resort)

[image]

Modeling this by hand would be extremely time consuming and I'm positive this could be done using mainly procedural methods like modifiers.

Comment: You sould try out the sverchok addon or animation nodes. Jimmy Gunawan has recently posted a video on how to acheive a similar result on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2QVSoN_51c

Comment: Do you need real geometry or is procedural volumetric material ok?

Comment: @Jimmy: Nice addon, I'll surely check this one out.

Comment: @Jerryno: Yes, I need real geometry. but this does not have to consist of one single mesh. As long as it's not obvious for the viewer.

Comment: @zeffii Here is a link to a very similar model
https://www.harolds.nl/images/producten/groot/prod__1382972819_groene-boomkruin1-650.jpg